# Can someone explain me the CDC::SelectObject to me?

Tags: mfc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa8ahz7h(v=vs.80).aspx

```
//Border
        CPen pen;
        pen.CreatePen(PS_DASH, 20, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        CPen* penOld = dc.SelectObject(&pen);

        dc.Rectangle(rect);
        dc.FillRect(rect, &brush);
```

How does this code work? It draws a rectangle and then a border around it. I just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ask the device context to draw a rectangle, it will use the current `Pen`.

You can set the current `Pen`, `Brush`, clipping region or whatever using the `SelectObject()` method. You're basically saying "use this Pen from now on".

`SelectObject()` also returns the item it was using before, so that it doesn't get lost and leak memory, and you can put it back later if you want. This is why `penOld` is being saved to a variable in your code. It will probably be selected back again later on.

```
CPen pen;                                  //declare a new Pen object
pen.CreatePen(PS_DASH, 20, RGB(0, 0, 0));  //Create the GDI Pen, dashed, 20 pixels wide, black.
CPen* penOld = dc.SelectObject(&pen);      //Tell the DC to use this pen from now on.

dc.Rectangle(rect);                        //Draw a rectangle (using the current pen)
dc.FillRect(rect, &brush);                 //Fill a rectangle (using the current brush)
```

Answer (score 0):

It creates a pen, selects it into the DC, and then instructs the DC to use the pen (which is 20 pixels wide) to draw a rectangle at the specified coordinates. It then fills in the inside of that rectangle with a brush.